# Unix: Grep on console output

Tags: unix, console, grep

This is my first question on stackoverflow!
I want to have a unix script that will run grep on the console output. Here is what my script does:
1. Telnet into a remote server (I have done this part successfully)
2. On successful login, the remote server displays outputs information on the console. I need to run grep on that console output (need help with this)

So, I need a script to run grep on the output appearing on the console.

Any thoughts??

Thanks,
Puneet

Comment: Do you now how `output` that you are referring to is generated? If you cannot plug `grep` there, you need to store the op somewhere and then do `grep` on it.

Answer (score 3):

Use SSH instead. It's more secure and far easier to script.

```
ssh remoteusername@remotehost:/path/to/remote/script | grep 'something'
```

with appropriate key setup, it won't even prompt you for a password.

Comment: Cannot use SSH, as the remote server only supports telnet!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried I/O redirection?  You could either do

```
$ your-command > output.txt
```

and then run grep on that file, or just directly pipe the output through grep like so

```
$ your-command | grep ...
```

See [this article](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles2/042.html) or google around for similar.  There are probably thousands of good articles about this around the web.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of telnet, I would suggest using [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) (nc). You could then pass your login credentials via standard input and grep the standard output (nc prints anything sent by the server on standard output).

```
nc <host> <port> <auth.txt | grep 'string'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is probably using a pipe. You can probably see it in the above answers it's the `|` sign you see in the command. It may be difficult to locate on your keyboard, depending on the layout. (I have to admit it is not very often used).

Pipes will redirect the output of one command. Instead of sending it to the console, they will send it as an input of another command.

`cmd1 | grep foo` is equivalent to running `grep foo` on the output of `cmd1` (you can replace cmd1 by your netstat command).

One last thing is that you can have as many pipes as you want. For instance on my machine I can run `ls -ltr | tail -1 | awk '{print $9}' | grep foo` to look for the word `foo` in the last modified file.